# Como printar o número que aparece ímpares vezes (Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x

```
num = input()
numerosString = num.split(" ")
numeros = [int(numero) for numero in numerosString] 
numeros.sort()
print(" ".join(map(str,numeros)))
```

A questão pede como saída na 1º linha a ordem crescente dos números dados (isso eu consegui completar), porém ele pede que na linha de baixo (2º linha), seja impresso o número que aparece ímpares vezes. Como faço para retornar esse número? OBS: não confundir com a QUANTIDADE de números que se repetem ímpares vezes, não é isso que quero, para esclarecer segue exemplos:

Quando receber: 1 2 3 1 2 3 4

O que deve retornar: "4" pois é o único número que apareceu impares vezes (1 vez é a quantidade)

Quando receber: 1 2 2 1 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 7 8 6 8 7 6 9 9

O que deve retornar: "6" pois é o único número que apareceu impares vezes (3 vezes é a quantidade)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Busque sempre a alternativa mais simples.

Use um contador [`collection.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) para saber quantas vezes um elemento se repetiu em uma lista e use o [resto da divisão](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) de um número por 2 para saber sua paridade:

```
from collections import Counter

num = input("Digite a lista de inteiros:\n")
numeros = list(map(int, num.split(" ")))      #Quebra a entrada numa lista de números.
numeros.sort()                                #Oredena a lista de números.

print(*numeros)                               #Imprime a a lista de ordenada números.

#Itera pelos itens do contador contador onde k é a chave(elemento da lista numeros) e v é o seu respectivo valor(quantidade de aparições do elemento na lista numeros)...
for k,v in Counter(numeros).items():
  #...se o número de aparições do número for impar...
  if v % 2 != 0:
    print(k, end=" ")                         #...o imprime na segunda linha.
```

Resultado:

```
Digite a lista de inteiros:
1 2 2 1 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 7 8 6 8 7 6 9 9
1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 6 7 7 8 8 9 9
6
```

<sup>Teste o código no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@RonaldoVasques/printarimpar#main.py)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi você quer implementar um script que seja capaz de exibir o(s) valor(es) cuja(s) contagem de suas ocorrências for um número ímpar.

Pois bem, para isso devemos montar a seguinte lógica:

1. Tomar os valores **SEM REPETIÇÕES** da lista passada;
2. Ordenar esses valores. Opcional. Exibe os resultados na saída em ordem crescente;
3. Montar um objeto iterável - podendo ser uma lista de listas ou um dicionário - contendo cada valor juntamente com a contagem de sua respectiva ocorrência;
4. Exibir o(s) valor(es) cuja contagem de ocorrências for um valor ímpar.

Seguindo esta lógica, podemos implementar um script com **lista de listas** ou com um **dicionário**.

**Implementação com lista de listas:**

```
def impares_vezes(li):
    return [j[0] for j in [[i, li.count(i)] for i in sorted(set(li))] if j[1] % 2]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    lista = list(map(int, input().split()))
    resp = impares_vezes(lista)

    print(*resp)
```

**Implementação com dicionário:**

```
def impares_vezes(li):
    return [k for k, v in {i: li.count(i) for i in sorted(set(li))}.items() if v % 2]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    lista = list(map(int, input().split()))
    resposta = impares_vezes(lista)

    print(*resposta)
```

Observe que quando executamos os dois referidos códigos, recebemos o cursor piscando no canto superior esquerdo da tela. Neste momento devemos digitar **todos** os valores da referida lista, na **mesma** linha, **separados** por um só espaço e pressionar <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Após isso, os valores listados serão passado como parâmetros para a função **impares_vezes()**. Chegando lá, os valores repetidos serão removidos e devidamente ordenados de forma crescente.

Posteriormente, de acordo com o script escolhido, será montada uma **lista de listas** ou um **dicionário** contendo, respectivamente o referido valor juntamente com a contagem de sua ocorrência.

Em seguida, será montada outra lista contendo apenas o(s) valor(es) cuja contagem de ocorrências resultar em um número ímpar.

**OBS:**

A última linha do código...

```
print(*resposta)
```

...está apenas desempacotando os possíveis valores armazenados na lista.